# Как работает метод paint? Почему не воспринимаются поля?

Tags: java, swing, графика, awt

Разбираюсь с методом `paint(Graphics)` у компонентов интерфейса. Столкнулся с такой интересной особенностью.

Допустим, я рисую чёрный прямоугольник внутри метода:

```
private class GraphicsArea extends JPanel{

    private float xn = 10f;
    private float yn = 10f;

   public void paint(Graphics g){
Graphics2D painter = (Graphics2D)g;
painter.setColor(Color.BLACK);
Rectangle2D graphicAreaRect = new Rectangle2D.Double(getX()+xn, getY()+yn, getWidth()-2*xn, getHeight()-2*yn);
 painter.draw(graphicAreaRect);
   }
}
```

В этом случае все работает и прямоугольник появляется. Но если я объявляю прямоугольник, как приватное поле, отрисовки не происходит.

```
    private class GraphicsArea extends JPanel{

    private float xn = 10f;
    private float yn = 10f;
    private Rectangle2D graphicAreaRect = new Rectangle2D.Double(getX()+xn, getY()+yn, getWidth()-2*xn, getHeight()-2*yn);

   public void paint(Graphics g){
Graphics2D painter = (Graphics2D)g;
painter.setColor(Color.BLACK);
painter.draw(graphicAreaRect);

   }
}
```

И так с любыми подобными фигурами. Почему так происходит? Метод не видит поля не примитивного типа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, методы `getX`, `getWidth` и т.п. в момент создания фигуры во втором случае возвращают значения, которые еще не отражают положения и размеров панели.